# get labeled files from TFS In cases where there are files with multiple labels

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

I need LABEL_A files for my deployment today , I use

```
tf label /server:http://tfs:8080 LABEL_B $/Project/Folder /recursive
tf label /server:http://tfs:8080 LABEL_B $/Project/Folder /recursive /version:LLABEL_A
```

Now I have LABEL_A files merged in LABEL_B.

Next day i need LABEL_C files(without LABEL_A files) for deployment. If i use this command -

```
tf label /server:http://tfs:8080 LABEL_B $/Project/Folder /recursive /version:LLABEL_C
```

i will get LABEL_C and LABEL_A merged in LABEL_B.
Is there a way to get LABEL_C alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its impossible. The `LABEL_B` of Next day(including LABEL_A) are different from  `LABEL_B` of your created. You can't simply split it.

Why you insist on replacing `LABEL_B` to use it? The simplest way is to create a new LABEL such as `LABEL_D` for `$/Project/Folder`. And then just merge it in `LABEL_D` and you will get `LABEL_C` alone.

**Labels mark a certain version of the files so that you can easily go back to that point.** In other words: It's kind of a back up of your computer system. Create one back up and replace it every month *vs*  Create serval back ups for each month. Which one do you prefer?

Here is a good discussion [TFS: Labels vs Changesets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956451/tfs-labels-vs-changesets)  about label for you reference.