# TF Build 2013 building specific version using changeset, label, buildNumber or buildId

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have two team builds created in VS 2013 - Dev and Test - using the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml build process template.  Both builds also use a custom .proj file defined in the process tab "Build/Projects" parameter.

Dev is set to Continuous Integration to build on each check-in.  For the Test build, I'd like to update to a particular version.

When firing the build manually, in the parameters tab, I have successfully been able to specify a Changeset in the "Get Version" option. (C9999)

1)  I'd like to eventually fire this build from command line, so is it possible to pass this in as a /msBuildArgument instead?  e.g. /p:GetVersion=C9999

(I've tried this, and it successfully passes GetVersion to my .proj files, but it does not override the iBuildDetail.SourceGetVersion, which I think is what needs to happen to tell MSBuild what version to get from source control.)

2)  Would using the "Label", "BuildId" or "BuildNumber" be better options, and if so, can I specifiy them as /msBuildArguments?

I have found a few related posts, but these offer suggestions that don't seem directed to 2013, but rather 2010 and 2008.

[This screenshot shows where I can successfully enter and build a specified changeset and what I'm attempting to pass via arguments.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMSU0.png)

Comment: I ran across this post that suggests using labels is the way to go.  How can I configure a build to use a certain label?  When I insert the label name into the "Get Version" field, it fails saying that ..."_LabelName_ is not a valid changeset number"   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956451/tfs-labels-vs-changesets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some buried documentation which indicates to prefix the label with an "L".  Setting *Get Version = "LlabelName"* did the trick.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490833.aspx#VersionSpecs

This is helpful, but it seems the labels are tied the to the build's retention policy. For this reason, I'll be using Changesets to specify the version I want to get (build and deploy).

Also, I found a couple parameters to specify Changeset (or labels) to add to the *TFSBuild start* command I am executing from the command line:

/getOption:Custom /customGetVersion:C9999   (or LlabelName)